# Append to extending pipeline job names

Tags: yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm struggling with extending a base template in Azure DevOps yaml pipelines. It seems even the simplest action is a challenge with no good resources, tools, documentation, and uninformative error messages. I'm using yamllint.com and the AzDO rest api for parsing yaml:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{org}}/{{project}}/_apis/pipelines/{{pielineId}}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview
```

Any other tools you can recommend would be helpful.

My question; I'd like to prepend jobs from the extending pipeline. Please explain why adding a join below does nothing.

This works as expected:

```
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition
  jobs:
  - ${{ each job in parameters.buildJobs }}:        
      ${{ if contains(job.displayName, '1') }}:
        job: ${{ 'thisIsATest' }}  
        steps:
        - ${{ job.steps }}
```

Result:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: basePipelineTemplatesHost/basePipelineTemplatesHost
    ref: refs/tags/v1
stages:
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition
  jobs:
  - job: thisIsATest
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo This is bash script 1
```

But trying to introduce a join does nothing:

```
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition
  jobs:
  - ${{ each job in parameters.buildJobs }}:        
      ${{ if contains(job.displayName, '1') }}:
        job: ${{ join('ext_',job.displayName) }}  
        steps:
        - ${{ job.steps }}
```

Result:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: basePipelineTemplatesHost/basePipelineTemplatesHost
    ref: refs/tags/v1
stages:
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo This is bash script 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to read what join was doing, it does not concat. Format was the function I needed to get the desired result!

```
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition2
  jobs:
  - ${{ each job in parameters.buildJobs }}:        
      ${{ if contains(job.displayName, '1') }}:
        job: ${{ format('ext_{0}',job.displayName) }}  
        steps:
        - ${{ job.steps }}
```

Result:

```
- stage: parseBuildJobsWithCondition2
  jobs:
  - job: ext_job1
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo This is bash script 1
```